# C restrict keyword

Tags: c, c11

I try to understand the meaning of the restrict keyword in C11 on the compiler optimization.

In compiler explorer I tested with the code below. But for the two functions use and use2, compiler produce the same assembly code (with ARM GCC 11 and X86 GCC 11)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void use(int* a, int* b, int* restrict c)
{
    *a += *c;
    *b += *c; 
}

void use2(int* a, int* b, int* c)
{
    *a += *c;
    *b += *c; 
}
 
int main(void)
{
    int a = 50, b = 60, c = 70;
    use(&a, &b, &c);
    printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Does someone has an example of use case of this keyword on compiler optimization?

Comment: Godbolt produces [different](https://godbolt.org/z/7KnY9Gfrs) code for the two functions. Edit: also, [different](https://godbolt.org/z/v3v99fob1) code for the two on arm.

Comment: And the different assembly can also produce different results. Try `use(&a, &b, &a);` with both versions. The promise about aliasing has consequences.

Comment: the function `use2` is never invoked, so is most likely optimized out of existence

Answer (score 6):

It generally tells the compiler that changing the contents pointed by `a` and `b` will not impact the contents pointed by `c`.

In other words, it tells the compiler that `c` points to a "safe" place in memory, unaffected by whatever you do with the other pointers.

The compiler assumes that if you change the contents pointed by `c`, then you do so only via that pointer.

This allows the compiler to optimize parts of your code where `c` is used for memory-read operations.